# Docker - pass username and password for git repository, that is downloaded via conanfile

Tags: docker, conan

I have the following problem: I am using Conan and in one of my conanfiles I am downloading from a private repository. That works so far, but when I am using Docker it complains that it doesn't have the username and password for this repository. Is there a recommended way to pass the username and password for a private repository to conan?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a c++ problem to me

Comment: You mean, like env-vars? You can define login and password environment variables: http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/env_vars.html#conan-login-username-conan-login-username-remote-name Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `conan`  but you can pass user and password in this scenario using [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/deploy-app/6_define_environment_variables/) and make some script that gets those values and configure `conan` or creating a config file and passes it with  [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command when you build your image with `Dockerfile`